# Select Default TreeView Item in MFC

Tags: c++, mfc, treeview

Below is the code used to fill the **treeview**. 
How could i make a selection default like **Monday** as the default. So that whenever the **dialog** is loaded **monday** is always selected.

```
CTreeCtrl m_treeSettings;

HTREEITEM hParent, hChild;
hParent = m_treeSettings.InsertItem(_T("Week Days"), TVI_ROOT);
hChild = m_treeSettings.InsertItem(_T("Sunday"), hParent);
hChild = m_treeSettings.InsertItem(_T("Monday"), hParent);
hChild = m_treeSettings.InsertItem(_T("Tuesday"), hParent);
hChild = m_treeSettings.InsertItem(_T("Wednesday"), hParent);
hChild = m_treeSettings.InsertItem(_T("Thrasday"), hParent);
hChild = m_treeSettings.InsertItem(_T("Friday"), hParent);
hChild = m_treeSettings.InsertItem(_T("Saturday"), hParent);

m_treeSettings.Expand(hParent,TVE_EXPAND);
```

Basically it is a CTreeCtrl and this entire code is executed in **OnInitDialog()**

[image: Treeview Image as Required]

Comment: You select an item by calling `SelectItem` on it. Fairly impossible to tell, which part you are having difficulty with, or what classes you are using.

Comment: Above code is working good. I just want to enable the Monday as default selected item onInitDialog()

Comment: Leaving aside, that it's still not clear, what the real issue was, the code you presented is not in the least locale-aware. Weekdays should be localized strings, and the start of the week is locale-specific. The code ignores this.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This code goes in **OnInitDialog()**. This help to achieve what i want to do. If anyone have better solution, then please guide.

```
HTREEITEM hParent, hMonday, hChild;
hParent = m_treeSettings.InsertItem(_T("Week Days"), TVI_ROOT);
hChild = m_treeSettings.InsertItem(_T("Sunday"), hParent);
hMonday = m_treeSettings.InsertItem(_T("Monday"), hParent);
hChild = m_treeSettings.InsertItem(_T("Tuesday"), hParent);
hChild = m_treeSettings.InsertItem(_T("Wednesday"), hParent);
hChild = m_treeSettings.InsertItem(_T("Thursday"), hParent);
hChild = m_treeSettings.InsertItem(_T("Friday"), hParent);
hChild = m_treeSettings.InsertItem(_T("Saturday"), hParent);

m_treeSettings.Expand(hParent,TVE_EXPAND);
m_treeSettings.SelectItem(hMonday);
m_treeSettings.SetFocus();
```

Comment: I am building a tree control also and find that this worked well in my project. Also, in your code `Thursday` is not spelled correctly!

Answer (score 0):

addition:

When you use tree control, it's better to use different variable for each handle.
ex: you used hChild for everything(Sunday, Monday...)

it works well when you just display, but it's difficult(maybe impossible) when you should work with specifically one handle.